# jQueryMobile icon issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I have a header, in that i am trying to user a icon on the left side corner. I have used jquerymobile icons in that page. But i cant able to see the icon symbol, only empty icon i displayed. Find the attached screenshot for reference. below is the code from html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="test">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: This might not be the issue, but why are using so old version of JQM?

Comment: the above i created for a reference, but i am using new jqm-1.3.2.js, jqm-1.3.2.css with jquery-1.9.1.js is a right combination of jquery & jqm

Comment: Happens on all browsers? If you add data-icon=home does it change anything?

Comment: I am testing in android phone only.

Comment: Just a suggestion but you could try using ripple with a browser to do testing.  I like it alot.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it in a fiddle and it seems to work OK for me. http://jsfiddle.net/LYCjv/

Might be worth downloading `jQueryMobile` hosting the files on your own server and referencing the css/js files locally, might be some issue with the CDN?